# I'm rnevius (not mevius): A font kerning issue with usernames

Tags: support, design, comment-replies, fonts

My username is `rnevius` (r n e v i u s). However, on ~20% of the @replies I get, I am incorrectly referred to as `mevius` (m e v i u s). Example:

[image]

You can even see this issue by looking at my username attached to this Meta question.

This is very clearly a font-kerning issue on some screens. Has the design team considered using a different font for comments / username display (or, at least, a different letter spacing)? Surely, I'm not the only person experiencing this issue...

Comment: I would just attribute this to the one replying being too hasty.  If the `@` doesn't give you an auto-complete suggestion, then you've likely got it wrong.

Comment: @MikeGuthrie , that's partially true. But given the frequency of the issue, I think this is still a problem. I shouldn't have to look at a username for more than a split second, or do a double take, or type multiple `@` names in order to guess a username so that I can reply to someone...

Comment: The gap can be seen pretty clear though, can't even force my eyes read m instead of rn.

Comment: @MikeGuthrie: The auto complete doesn't always come up. If you are addressing the post owner and there are no other comments from others, it wouldn't show up.

Comment: @nicael , again, this is dependent upon screen resolution. I don't see this issue on a retina screen, or HD display. Do you see a gap in the attached screenshot? I don't (unless I squint).

Comment: @Harry That's true, but as the post owner, you'd get the notification anyway, making it a non-issue.

Comment: @MikeGuthrie: Totally agreed, I just wanted to say that they may not necessarily have got it wrong.

Comment: The screenshot has something other than a gap (though there's a small). r ends higher than the arc of n begins, so they're still distinguishable.

Comment: @nicael: Maybe to you, but to these old eyes it's hard to see the difference. At least in Chrome on Windows.

Comment: when i read the title from the question list, i couldn't figure out immediately what you were trying to say because i saw "i'm mevius (not mevius) .."

Comment: Wow I thought it was mevius too...lol

Comment: Nothing SE can do here. They won't change the font just for the sake of single display name that people get wrong. If you're really worried about not getting notifications for comments aimed at you, just change the name. (e.g. to your full name Ryan Nevius or just Ryan N. etc.)

Comment: I am not Skliwz, either, and I feel your feels.

Comment: @Sklivvz I think vv or w is more visible than rn or m.

Comment: The font used in the iOS app doesn't have this problem. :)

Comment: Nor the Android app.

Comment: Hashtag rne too.

Answer (score 7):

The "r" could use a little hook at the end to allow the users to stop thinking that "rn" is actually "m". Spacing also seems to be an issue, so I guess moderators should try making combinations of characters that look like other characters have more spacing in between or make the letters more explicit.

What is even worse, is that when you hover over you username...

If you change Calibri (I think that's the font) to something similar to Times New Roman, you get this:

[image]

A slight spacing between characters that look like they are touching each other would be more appreciated than a change in the font though, like this (viewing source code for this page):

[image]

Comment: It's important to note that Chrome's "View Source" page uses `font-family: monospace;`, while Stack Exchange usernames are rendered in `'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif`